# Resolution of the screen is not setting properly

Tags: browser, protractor, resolution

I m trying to set my browser screen with resolution of (360,640) but when i m reading, it is changed in value and there is a difference in set values and get values

```
 resolution(){
        browser.manage().window().setSize(360,640);
        browser.manage().window().getSize().then((getSize) => {
              console.log('Value of Height', getSize.height);
              console.log('Value of width', getSize.width);
        });
    }
NOTE :: tried with different resolution and their result as below:
1.Width :: 360 and Height :: 640  
Result is coming as Width:: 516 and Height :: 640

2.Width ::768  and Height :: 1024
Result is coming as Width :: 768 and Height :: 788

Using Protractor Version :: Version 5.4.3
      npm :: 6.14.5


Please help me out to solve this problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try setting the resolution on capabilities instead of creating a resolution function for it. Like this:

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1440,960"]
        },
    }
```

Also alternately you can add the browser.window setSize inside your onPrepare function like this:

```
onPrepare: async() => {
        browser.baseUrl = 'https://app.thegaas.com';
        await browser.driver.manage().window().setPosition(0,0);
        await browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1440,960);
        let getSize = await browser.driver.manage().window().getSize();
        console.log('Value of Height', getSize.height);
        console.log('Value of width', getSize.width);
    }
```

You can remove the async await and resolve the promises using .then instead.

Comment: Thank you so much Sankalan ....it is working fine....But is there any other way to work around this with non-headless mode

Comment: You could remove the --headless flag from chromeOptions. Is that not working? Are you trying to run these in the CI?

Comment: Hi Sankalan..I have tried to run my test case without --headless...Issue is reproducible.I can see the difference in the width of chrome browser. It is not working . I m trying to run in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Have you tried the onPrepare function as well? Does it give the same result?